# multiple value in sequential order (SQL)

Tags: sql, database, group-by, distinct

I am trying to write a SQL query that customers who have transactions in the exact following order of merchants: clothes shop, coffee shop, then restaurant.

Table schemas

> txndate |cust_id |merchant_name |

how to list customers who have transactions in the exact following order of merchants and with conditions if customer have transactions in the same merchant multiple times in sequential order then it counts as one appearance?
for example: `clothes shop, coffee shop, coffee shop, restaurant, coffee shop`  will be `clothes shop, coffee shop, restaurant, coffee shop`

Thankyou

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only the tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: Can you give us a [reproduceable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and what you've tried so far.